# Confusion about Vertical-Align (CSS)

Tags: css, vertical-alignment

Can someone explain vertical-align.
I have few examples here ,with vertical-align:top/bottom/middle 
I am confused about their placement. I did not find a proper understanding of vertical alignment .Please help me with this

http://www.htmlandcssbook.com/code-samples/chapter-05/aligning-images-vertically.html

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

First off, I'm recommend you use vertical-align in css not on HTML tag.

<del>And next, Vertical-align was place your text or img... any element inside the parent tag to position you set on it base according in your parent's element real height.</del>

hmm, I misunderstanding it, 
for vertical-align, it place your element inside a parent's tag base on all element but the max's height.

It effect other siblings of this element, like text or all inline style (inline-* also too).

From the article we read, they are only place text.

### **that article mention**

> Unfortunately vertical-align doesn’t apply to block-level elements like a paragraph inside a div.

what if we want to vertical-align text inside a div tag, we have declared the element's height for them, that's why we have use :before or :after to set height: 100% to fulfill element parent's height.

With inline style to make it stand on a line, so now the element have their own height comparison from :before or :after.

more detail you can see on W3C [vertical-align](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_vertical-align.asp)

 for a example below:

```css
.box{
  height:150px;
  width: auto;
  background: pink;
  border: 1px solid black;
  }
.top-line{
  vertical-align: top;
}
.middle-line{
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.bottom-line{
  vertical-align: bottom;
}
.text_Valine:before{
  content:'';
  display:inline-block;
  height:100%; 
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"> I'm <img class="top-line" src="http://www.htmlandcssbook.com/code-samples/chapter-05/images/bird.gif" alt=""> vertical-align top </div>
<div class="box"> I'm <img class="middle-line" src="http://www.htmlandcssbook.com/code-samples/chapter-05/images/bird.gif" alt=""> vertical-align middle</div>
<div class="box bottom-line"> I'm <img class="bottom-line" src="http://www.htmlandcssbook.com/code-samples/chapter-05/images/bird.gif" alt=""> vertical-align bottom </div>

<div class="box text_Valine">Only Valign text</div>
```

Comment: Or here is an article to explain more detail http://christopheraue.net/2014/02/20/centering-with-vertical-align-middle/

Comment: I dont think your code works, because in the same article it is metioned as vertical-align would work only for inline/inline-block elements ...Here is the link to it http://christopheraue.net/2014/03/05/vertical-align/

Comment: I just made some changes, yes that's my fail, I didn't thinking clear...